# Find the Value Within a Column Which is First Not Found

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have to write a SQL where in I have to write SQL for calculating the `RunID` first not seen. Let me explain with an example

Ex:

```
RunID | RunDate    | ErrorID
----- | ---------- | ---------
101   | 04/11/2017 | 1
101   | 04/11/2017 | 2
101   | 04/11/2017 | 3
102   | 04/22/2017 | 2
102   | 04/22/2017 | 3
103   | 04/26/2017 | 1
104   | 04/27/2017 | 3
105   | 04/28/2017 | 4
```

In the above example RunID 101 has errors 1,2,3. RunID 102 has 2,3. During second run ErrorID 1 is not found. So, RunID first not seen here till now is 102
But ErrorID 1 is found again in RunID 103 and finally ErrorID 1 is not found in RunID 104. Query should give the RunIDs like 104 which are first not found.

I have tried using some window functions like lead and lag but it doesn't help.

Here are the expected results:

Date first not seen for ErrorID : 2

```
RunID | RunDate    | ErrorID
----- | ---------- | ---------
103   | 04/26/2017 | 2
```

Because ErrorID 2 was never seen(first instance of not seen) after RunID-102

Date first not seen for ErrorID : 1

```
RunID | RunDate    | ErrorID
----- | ---------- | ---------
104   | 04/27/2017 | 1
```

ErrorID 1 was never seen after RunID-104

Date first not seen for ErrorID : 3

```
RunID | RunDate    | ErrorID
----- | ---------- | ---------
105   | 04/28/2017 | 3
```

ErrorID 3 was never seen after RunID-105

Comment: Show expected results.  Your question is unclear but expected results should help clarify.

Comment: edited the post, please check now

Comment: but error_id 1 first not met in run 102?..

Comment: RunID 102 has ErrorID 2,3 only... other ErrorID 1 is not found in this run

Comment: What on the Earth database you are using?

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you can't answer a question don't give negative points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Get the last runDate when an errorID was seen
with t1 as (select runId,runDate,errorID
            ,first_value(runDate) over(partition by errorID order by runDate desc 
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_seen
            from tablename
           )
--Get the next runDate based on the previous result
,t2 as (select runid,errorID,runDate
        ,(select min(runDate) from t1 t11 where t11.runDate>t1.last_seen) as date_first_not_seen
        from t1
       )
--Join it to the original table to get the runID information from that runDate in the previous result (t2)
select distinct t.runid,t2.errorid,t.rundate
from t2
join tablename t on t.rundate=t2.date_first_not_seen
```

or

```
with t1 as (select runId,runDate,errorID
            ,first_value(runDate) over(partition by errorID order by runDate desc 
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_seen
            from tablename)
select distinct
 t1.errorid
,first_value(t.runDate) over(partition by t1.errorID order by t1.runDate desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as rundate
,first_value(t.runID) over(partition by t1.errorID order by t1.runDate desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as runid
from t1
join tablename t on t.runDate>t1.last_seen
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/FWV90478)

Answer (score 1):

```
so=> with l as (
with m as (
  select distinct max(runid) over(partition by errorid),errorid
  from so80
)
, a as (
  select distinct runid,errorid
  from so80
)
select distinct min(a.runid) over (partition by m.errorid),m.errorid
from m
join a on m.max < a.runid
)
select s.*
from so80 s
join l on l.min=s.runid and s.errorid=s.errorid

;
 runid |   rundate    | errorid
-------+--------------+---------
   104 |  04/27/2017  |       3
   103 |  04/26/2017  |       1
   105 |  04/28/2017  |       4
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Vao .. this will not work as expected if runID's aren't in the same order as runDates, i.e. increasing with runDates.

Comment: @vkp I assumed he OP wants to order by runid - he always mentions first runid where errorid not met, not date... anyway won't change as you already gave answer for ordering my date :)